# Using key `action` is deprecated, use `url` directly instead in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am getting this error in CakePHP from my forgot_password method which is in UsersController.

```
public function forgot_password() {
    $this->layout = 'signin';
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $user = $this->User->findByUsername($this->data['User']['username']);
        if (empty($user)) {
            $this->Session->setflash('Sorry, the username entered was not found.');
            $this->redirect('/users/forgot_password');
            }else{
                $user = $this->__generatePasswordToken($user);
                if ($this->User->save($user) && $this->__sendForgotPasswordEmail($user['User']['id'])) {
                $this->Session->setflash('Password reset instructions have been sent to your email address.
                    You have 24 hours to complete the request.');
                $this->redirect('/users/login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the forgot_password.ctp file

```
<header class="panel-heading text-center">
    <strong>Forget Password</strong>
</header>
    <h3>Enter Your Username</h3>
<?php 
     echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'forgot_password', 'id' => 'web-form', 'class'=>'panel-body wrapper-lg')); 

     echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Username', 'between'=>'<br />', 'type'=>'text', 'div' => 'form-group','class' => 'form-control input-lg')); 
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Send Password Reset Instructions', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-techuz', 'id' => 'submit')); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not necessary to specify the form action if it's same as the view. In case you'd like to redirect to a different action, try this:

```
   <?php 
      echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
          'url'   => array(
               'controller' => 'users','action' => 'forgot_password'
           ), 
          'id'    => 'web-form', 
          'class' =>'panel-body wrapper-lg'
       )
    ); ?>
```

If you follow the convention and define this "url" index as an array of controller and index, you're bound to be safe and deprived of errors.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, no need to mention 'action' => 'forgot_password' in forgot_password.ctp file until it is redirect to another method.